# Jetty ConcatServlet to handle filter generated content

Tags: servlets, jetty, servlet-filters, wro4j

I try to use jetty's `ConcatServlet` to concatenate javascript generated from my own servlet and javascript generated by wro4j `WroFilter`. It seems concatenation doesn't work, regardless the javadoc of `ConcatServlet` that states that it can be used to concat generated content.

I think the issue is that the wro4j content is generated by a filter an not a servlet as 'concatenating' a single source generated by my servlet works fine, while 'concatenating' the single wro4j generated resource doesn't work but I get the exception below. It complaints about a missing file, although the request /wro/script.js is served fine if requested normally. Any suggestions?

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: !/wro/script.js
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:465)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:586)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.include(Dispatcher.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.ConcatServlet.doGet(ConcatServlet.java:122)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:695)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1535)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$1.run(AbstractConnection.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:532)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: The /wro/script.js is a virtual resource, it doesn't actually exist on the servlet context.  This is why you get java.io.FileNotFoundException. I don't understand why you don't use the filter only?

Comment: Because my another js file is also generated. (It contains i18n messages in JSON format based on a text file)

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. Wro4j is capable of handling dynamically generated resources.

Comment: Hmm.. I tried adding <js>/msg.js</js> into my wro4j config, but it has no effect; (/msg.js is generated by my custom servlet.)

Comment: How is your servlet mapped? Is it mapped to root? What happens when you are trying to access the /msg.js resource in the browser? Do you see it? If yes, then wro4j should also be able to locate it and process properly. If you cannot fix this problem, feel free to open an issue on the wro4j project page.

Comment: very simple mapping: 

`<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MessagesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>mypackage.MessagesServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MessagesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/msg.js</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39445/discussion-between-alex-objelean-and-tamas)